# Como remuevo un elemento particular de una arreglo en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un arreglo de enteros, estoy usando el metodo `.push()` para agregar elementos a este. Existe una manera sencilla de remover un elemento del arreglo?. EL equivalente a algo como:

```
array.remove(int);
```

Debo usar javascript puro sin frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero encuentre el index de el elemento que quiere quitar:

```
var array=[2,5,9];
var index = array.indexOf(5);
```

Despues quita el elemento con splice

```
if(index > -1) {
  array.splice(index,1);
}
```

El segundo parametro del splice es el numero de elementos a remover. Norese que el arreglo hace el splice y retorna un array nuevo que contiene elementos que han sido removidos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar:

```
delete array[int];
```

Donde array es la variable del array e int la clave a borrar. Un saludo.